# Создание сервера(Tomcat 7) в Eclipse. Проблема

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

[image]

[image]

Скачал поседний Tomcat(7.0.39), установил его(у меня Win7), пытаюсь добавить его в Eclipse, но происходит вот такое. В кадр не попало, во втором случае(нужный мне), кнопка next просто не доступна. Как можно решить?

Comment: Возможно не видит установленного сервера. 
Можно конечно воспользоватся WinScanner и сделать кнопку активной :D.

Comment: Я вроде и переменные среды для Тома поставил, не знаю в чем дело, попробую на другой Eclipse прикрутить)

Comment: > Возможно не видит установленного сервера. Можно конечно воспользоватся WinScanner и сделать кнопку активной :D.

нельзя, потому что с точки зрения windows окно эклипс это большое серое пятно на экране

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы server runtime добавили к eclipse? `windows -> preferences -> server -> runtime environments`